# Jekyll build bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

I'm building a website in Jekyll (which i'm new to) and when I serve my website to my localhost, the navbar is showing up incorrectly. From all the sites I've ever used Bootstrap with, this has never happened. It seems as if the screen reader option is being chosen, but then again, I'm fairly new to Jekyll.

[image: The navbar]

On the navbar, there should be the default buttons showing up on the right hand side of it with the four options.

Here's my HTML:

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top main-navbar site-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-menu-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="navbar-menu">Menu</span>
        </button>
       <a class="site-title navbar-brand" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">Web Site</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a {% if page.url contains 'about' %}class="current-page"{% endif %} href="{{site.baseurl}}/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a {% if page.url contains 'portfolio' %}class="current-page"{% endif %} href="{{site.baseurl}}/portfolio">Work</a></li>
          <li><a {% if page.url contains 'blog' %}class="current-page"{% endif %} href="{{site.baseurl}}/blog">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a {% if page.url contains 'contact' %}class="current-page"{% endif %} href="{{site.baseurl}}/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ site.baseurl }}/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</header>
```

Comment: I don't see the Bootstrap CSS file being included in the HTML, it's probably what is missing

Comment: Since it's Jekyll, I have the Bootstrap SASS referenced in my main.scss so it should do the same thing as just including it in the HTML

Comment: is it also including Angular? just curious about {{ }} being used.

Comment: You should post your `main.css` and how your `_sass` directory is set up

Comment: Do you have a code repository somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole `nav` element and its sub elements should not be inside the `header` element, but in the `body` element.